I'm trying to hide information in a H264 video. When I stitch the video up, split it into frames again and try to read it, the information is lost
I'm trying to create a video steganography python script. The algorithm for hiding will be...

convert any video codec into h264 lossless
save the audio of the video and split the h264 video into frames
hide my txt secret into frame0 using LSB replacement method
stitch the video back up and put in the audio

...and when I want to recover the text, I'll

save the audio of the video and split the encoded h264 video into frames
retrieve my hidden text from frame0 and print the text

So, this is what I can do:

split the video
hide the text in frame0
retrieve the text from frame0
stitch the video

But after stitching the video, when I tried to retrieve the text by splitting that encrypted video, it appears that the text has been lost. This is because i got the error
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x82' in position 21: character maps to <undefined>

I'm not sure if my LSB replacement algorithm was lost, which results in my not being able to retrieve my frame 0 information, or if the H264 conversion command I used was a converted my video into H264 lossy version instead of lossless (which I don't believe so because I specified -qp 0)
This was the command I used to convert my video
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -t 12 -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -qp 0 output.mp4

These are my codes
import json
import os
import magic
import ffmpeg
import cv2
import numpy as np

import subprocess

# Path to the file you want to check
here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
file_path = os.path.join(here, "output.mp4")
raw_video = cv2.VideoCapture(file_path)
audio_output_path = os.path.join(here, "audio.aac")
final_video_file = os.path.join(here, "output.mp4")

# create a folder to save the frames.
frames_directory = os.path.join(here, "data1")
try:
    if not os.path.exists(frames_directory):
        os.makedirs(frames_directory)
except OSError:
    print("Error: Creating directory of data")

file_path_txt = os.path.join(here, "hiddentext.txt")
# Read the content of the file in binary mode
with open(file_path_txt, "r") as f:
    file_content = f.read()
# txt_binary_representation = "".join(format(byte, "08b") for byte in file_content)
# print(file_content)

"""
use this cmd to convert any video to h264 lossless. original vid in 10 bit depth format
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -qp 0 output.mp4

use this cmd to convert any video to h264 lossless. original vid in 8 bit depth format
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 0 output.mp4

i used this command to only get first 12 sec of video because the h264 vid is too large 
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -t 12 -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -qp 0 output.mp4

check for multiple values to ensure its h264 lossless:
1. CRF = 0
2. qp = 0
3. High 4:4:4 Predictive
"""


# region --codec checking. ensure video is h264 lossless--
def check_h264_lossless(file_path):
    try:
        # Use ffprobe to get detailed codec information, including tags
        result = subprocess.run(
            [
                "ffprobe",
                "-v",
                "error",
                "-show_entries",
                "stream=codec_name,codec_long_name,profile,level,bit_rate,avg_frame_rate,nb_frames,tags",
                "-of",
                "json",
                file_path,
            ],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            text=True,
        )
        # Check if the file is lossless
        metadata = check_h264_lossless(file_path)
        print(json.dumps(metadata, indent=4))

        # Check if the CRF value is available in the tags
        for stream in metadata.get("streams", []):
            if stream.get("codec_name") == "h264":
                tags = stream.get("tags", {})
                crf_value = tags.get("crf")
                encoder = tags.get("encoder")
                print(f"CRF value: {crf_value}")
                print(f"Encoder: {encoder}")
        return json.loads(result.stdout)
    except Exception as e:
        return f"An error occurred: {e}"


# endregion


# region --splitting video into frames--
def extract_audio(input_video_path, audio_output_path):
    if os.path.exists(audio_output_path):
        print(f"Audio file {audio_output_path} already exists. Skipping extraction.")
        return
    command = [
        "ffmpeg",
        "-i",
        input_video_path,
        "-q:a",
        "0",
        "-map",
        "a",
        audio_output_path,
    ]
    try:
        subprocess.run(command, check=True)
        print(f"Audio successfully extracted to {audio_output_path}")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")


def split_into_frames():
    extract_audio(file_path, audio_output_path)
    currentframe = 0
    print("Splitting...")
    while True:
        ret, frame = raw_video.read()
        if ret:
            name = os.path.join(here, "data1", f"frame{currentframe}.png")
            # print("Creating..." + name)
            cv2.imwrite(name, frame)
            currentframe += 1
        else:
            print("Complete")
            break


# endregion


# region --merge all back into h264 lossless--
# output_video_file = "output1111.mp4"


def stitch_frames_to_video(frames_dir, output_video_path, framerate=60):
    command = [
        "ffmpeg",
        "-y",
        "-framerate",
        str(framerate),
        "-i",
        os.path.join(frames_dir, "frame%d.png"),
        "-c:v",
        "libx264",
        "-preset",
        "veryslow",
        "-qp",
        "0",
        output_video_path,
    ]

    try:
        subprocess.run(command, check=True)
        print(f"Video successfully created at {output_video_path}")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")


def add_audio_to_video(video_path, audio_path, final_output_path):
    command = [
        "ffmpeg",
        "-i",
        video_path,
        "-i",
        audio_path,
        "-c:v",
        "copy",
        "-c:a",
        "aac",
        "-strict",
        "experimental",
        final_output_path,
    ]
    try:
        subprocess.run(command, check=True)
        print(f"Final video with audio created at {final_output_path}")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")


# endregion


def to_bin(data):
    if isinstance(data, str):
        return "".join([format(ord(i), "08b") for i in data])
    elif isinstance(data, bytes) or isinstance(data, np.ndarray):
        return [format(i, "08b") for i in data]
    elif isinstance(data, int) or isinstance(data, np.uint8):
        return format(data, "08b")
    else:
        raise TypeError("Type not supported")


def encode(image_name, secret_data):
    image = cv2.imread(image_name)
    n_bytes = image.shape[0] * image.shape[1] * 3 // 8
    print("[*] Maximum bytes to encode:", n_bytes)
    secret_data += "====="
    if len(secret_data) > n_bytes:
        raise ValueError("[!] Insufficient bytes, need bigger image or less data")
    print("[*] Encoding Data")

    data_index = 0
    binary_secret_data = to_bin(secret_data)
    data_len = len(binary_secret_data)
    for row in image:
        for pixel in row:
            r, g, b = to_bin(pixel)
            if data_index < data_len:
                pixel[0] = int(r[:-1] + binary_secret_data[data_index], 2)
                data_index += 1
            if data_index < data_len:
                pixel[1] = int(g[:-1] + binary_secret_data[data_index], 2)
                data_index += 1
            if data_index < data_len:
                pixel[2] = int(b[:-1] + binary_secret_data[data_index], 2)
                data_index += 1
            if data_index >= data_len:
                break
    return image


def decode(image_name):
    print("[+] Decoding")
    image = cv2.imread(image_name)
    binary_data = ""
    for row in image:
        for pixel in row:
            r, g, b = to_bin(pixel)
            binary_data += r[-1]
            binary_data += g[-1]
            binary_data += b[-1]
    all_bytes = [binary_data[i : i + 8] for i in range(0, len(binary_data), 8)]
    decoded_data = ""
    for byte in all_bytes:
        decoded_data += chr(int(byte, 2))
        if decoded_data[-5:] == "=====":
            break
    return decoded_data[:-5]


frame0_path = os.path.join(here, "data1", "frame0.png")
encoded_image_path = os.path.join(here, "data1", "frame0.png")


def encoding_function():
    split_into_frames()

    encoded_image = encode(frame0_path, file_content)
    cv2.imwrite(encoded_image_path, encoded_image)

    stitch_frames_to_video(frames_directory, file_path)
    add_audio_to_video(file_path, audio_output_path, final_video_file)


def decoding_function():
    split_into_frames()
    decoded_message = decode(encoded_image_path)
    print(f"[+] Decoded message: {decoded_message}")


# encoding_function()
decoding_function()


So I tried to put my decoding function into my encoding function like this
def encoding_function():
    split_into_frames()

    encoded_image = encode(frame0_path, file_content)
    cv2.imwrite(encoded_image_path, encoded_image)

#immediately get frame0 and decode without stitching to check if the data is there
    decoded_message = decode(encoded_image_path)
    print(f"[+] Decoded message: {decoded_message}")

    stitch_frames_to_video(frames_directory, file_path)
    add_audio_to_video(file_path, audio_output_path, final_video_file)


This returns my secret text from frame0. But splitting it after stitching does not return my hidden text. The hidden text was lost
def decoding_function():
    split_into_frames()
#this function is after the encoding_function(). the secret text is lost, resulting in charmap codec #can't encode error
    decoded_message = decode(encoded_image_path)
    print(f"[+] Decoded message: {decoded_message}")

EDIT:
So i ran the encoding function first, copied frame0.png out and placed it some where. Then I ran the decoding function, and got another frame0.png.
I ran both frame0.png into this python function
frame0_data1_path = os.path.join(here, "data1", "frame0.png")
frame0_data2_path = os.path.join(here, "data2", "frame0.png")
frame0_data1 = cv2.imread(frame0_data1_path)
frame0_data2 = cv2.imread(frame0_data2_path)

if frame0_data1 is None:
    print(f"Error: Could not load image from {frame0_data1_path}")
elif frame0_data2 is None:
    print(f"Error: Could not load image from {frame0_data2_path}")
else:

    if np.array_equal(frame0_data1, frame0_data2):
        print("The frames are identical.")
    else:
        print("The frames are different.")

...and apparently both are different. This means my frame0 binary got changed when I stitch back into the video after encoding. Is there a way to make it not change? Or will h264 or any video codec change a little bit when you stitch the frames back up?

Ok I looked around and found out that no matter how well ffmpeg tries to convert a video format to h264 lossless, it will still have loss, causing the lsb to get mutated. Hence, I switched up the format from h264 to a truly lossless ffv1, and my message can work now.
import json
import os
import magic
import ffmpeg
import cv2
import numpy as np
import subprocess

"""
use this cmd to convert any video to ffv1
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -t 12 -c:v ffv1 -level 3 -coder 1 -context 1 -g 1 -slices 4 -slicecrc 1 -c:a copy output.mkv
"""

# Path to the file you want to check
here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
file_path = os.path.join(here, "output.mkv")
raw_video = cv2.VideoCapture(file_path)
audio_output_path = os.path.join(here, "audio.aac")
final_video_file = os.path.join(here, "output.mv")

# create a folder to save the frames.
frames_directory = os.path.join(here, "data1")
try:
    if not os.path.exists(frames_directory):
        os.makedirs(frames_directory)
except OSError:
    print("Error: Creating directory of data")

file_path_txt = os.path.join(here, "hiddentext.txt")
# Read the content of the file in binary mode
with open(file_path_txt, "r") as f:
    file_content = f.read()


# region --splitting video into frames--
def extract_audio(input_video_path, audio_output_path):
    if os.path.exists(audio_output_path):
        print(f"Audio file {audio_output_path} already exists. Skipping extraction.")
        return
    command = [
        "ffmpeg",
        "-i",
        input_video_path,
        "-q:a",
        "0",
        "-map",
        "a",
        audio_output_path,
    ]
    try:
        subprocess.run(command, check=True)
        print(f"Audio successfully extracted to {audio_output_path}")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")


def split_into_frames():
    extract_audio(file_path, audio_output_path)
    currentframe = 0
    print("Splitting...")
    while True:
        ret, frame = raw_video.read()
        if ret:
            name = os.path.join(here, "data1", f"frame{currentframe}.png")
            # print("Creating..." + name)
            cv2.imwrite(name, frame)
            currentframe += 1
        else:
            print("Complete")
            break


# endregion


# region --merge all back into ffv1--
def stitch_frames_to_video(frames_dir, output_video_path, framerate=60):
    command = [
        "ffmpeg",
        "-y",
        "-framerate",
        str(framerate),
        "-i",
        os.path.join(frames_dir, "frame%d.png"),
        "-c:v",
        "ffv1",
        "-level",
        "3",
        "-coder",
        "1",
        "-context",
        "1",
        "-g",
        "1",
        "-slices",
        "4",
        "-slicecrc",
        "1",
        output_video_path,
    ]

    try:
        subprocess.run(command, check=True)
        print(f"Video successfully created at {output_video_path}")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")


def add_audio_to_video(video_path, audio_path, final_output_path):
    command = [
        "ffmpeg",
        "-y",
        "-i",
        video_path,
        "-i",
        audio_path,
        "-c:v",
        "copy",
        "-c:a",
        "aac",
        "-strict",
        "experimental",
        final_output_path,
    ]
    try:
        subprocess.run(command, check=True)
        print(f"Final video with audio created at {final_output_path}")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")


# endregion


def to_bin(data):
    if isinstance(data, str):
        return "".join([format(ord(i), "08b") for i in data])
    elif isinstance(data, bytes) or isinstance(data, np.ndarray):
        return [format(i, "08b") for i in data]
    elif isinstance(data, int) or isinstance(data, np.uint8):
        return format(data, "08b")
    else:
        raise TypeError("Type not supported")


def encode(image_name, secret_data):
    image = cv2.imread(image_name)
    n_bytes = image.shape[0] * image.shape[1] * 3 // 8
    print("[*] Maximum bytes to encode:", n_bytes)
    secret_data += "====="
    if len(secret_data) > n_bytes:
        raise ValueError("[!] Insufficient bytes, need bigger image or less data")
    print("[*] Encoding Data")

    data_index = 0
    binary_secret_data = to_bin(secret_data)
    data_len = len(binary_secret_data)
    for row in image:
        for pixel in row:
            r, g, b = to_bin(pixel)
            if data_index < data_len:
                pixel[0] = int(r[:-1] + binary_secret_data[data_index], 2)
                data_index += 1
            if data_index < data_len:
                pixel[1] = int(g[:-1] + binary_secret_data[data_index], 2)
                data_index += 1
            if data_index < data_len:
                pixel[2] = int(b[:-1] + binary_secret_data[data_index], 2)
                data_index += 1
            if data_index >= data_len:
                break
    return image


def decode(image_name):
    print("[+] Decoding")
    image = cv2.imread(image_name)
    binary_data = ""
    for row in image:
        for pixel in row:
            r, g, b = to_bin(pixel)
            binary_data += r[-1]
            binary_data += g[-1]
            binary_data += b[-1]
    all_bytes = [binary_data[i : i + 8] for i in range(0, len(binary_data), 8)]
    decoded_data = ""
    for byte in all_bytes:
        decoded_data += chr(int(byte, 2))
        if decoded_data[-5:] == "=====":
            break
    return decoded_data[:-5]


frame0_path = os.path.join(here, "data1", "frame0.png")
encoded_image_path = os.path.join(here, "data1", "frame0.png")


def encoding_function():
    split_into_frames()

    encoded_image = encode(frame0_path, file_content)
    cv2.imwrite(encoded_image_path, encoded_image)

    stitch_frames_to_video(frames_directory, file_path)
    add_audio_to_video(file_path, audio_output_path, final_video_file)


def decoding_function():
    split_into_frames()
    decoded_message = decode(encoded_image_path)
    print(f"[+] Decoded message: {decoded_message}")


# encoding_function()
decoding_function()


